# In the if else statement if statement is always true and else block is not executed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the console.log  this statement *"/es|ar|en/.test(window.location.pathname"* is always true, even when the path does not include
available languages of i18n and because of that the else block is not executed.
The else block should be executed when the user inserts unavailable language, for example *"ru"* in the path and redirect to back. But when the pathname includes *"en", "es" or "ar" * after page reloading the user should be stay in the same page.With the include method i can check only one value, i want to check multiple ones.How can i check whether path includes languages or not in other way? or what i did wrong in the below statement?.

```
 useEffect(() => {
        if (/es|ar|en/.test(window.location.pathname)) {
            history.push(window.location.pathname)
        }
        else {
            history.goBack()

        }
    }, [window.location]);
```

Comment: Not likely. `let pathname="/xx"; console.log(/es|ar|en/.test(pathname))` gives false

Comment: es, ar, en are languages why do i  need to define a variable and assign the same values.I want to check window.location.href or window.location.pathname dynamically.

Comment: I’m sorry I do not understand your comment or problem. Your code is testing 3 values at the same time…

Comment: The problem is i want to check the window.location.href in the if else block dynamically. If the pathname includes above mentioned languages to stay in the same page, but if the pathname does not include languages reload the page and show the available language. Want to change this        
if (window.location.href.includes("/es/")) {
history.push(window.location.pathname)}
if (window.location.href.includes("/ar/")) {
history.push(window.location.pathname)}
if (window.location.href.includes("/en/")) {
history.push(window.location.pathname}}
else {history.goBack()

   
```